# Rails controller path not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My form tag in my view:

```
<%= form_tag view_all_rater_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => 'Search by Set # or date' %></br>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-link", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My controller action:

```
  def view_all
    if params[:search]
      @ratings = RatingSet.find(:all, :conditions => ['id = ? or rating_date like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
    else
      @ratings = RatingSet.all
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :rater, :only => [:index] do
    collection do
      get :rater_csv
      get :view_all
    end
  end
```

When I navigate to /rater/view_all I get a `No route matches {:action=>"view_all", :controller=>"rater"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is going to be singular vs. plurals in your route definitions.

Your routes gives the following output for `rake routes`:

```
rater_csv_rater_index GET    /rater/rater_csv(.:format)                                  rater#rater_csv
 view_all_rater_index GET    /rater/view_all(.:format)                                   rater#view_all
          rater_index GET    /rater(.:format)                                            rater#index
```

Because you've defined a plural resource (`resources`) with a singular name (`rater`).

If you make it a singular resource (`resource`) the routes will clear themselves up.

And always always remember to use `rake routes`!

Comment: When I run rake routes after changes my route to a single resource I get: `rater_csv_rater GET    /rater/rater_csv(.:format)                 raters#rater_csv
                    view_all_rater GET    /rater/view_all(.:format)                  raters#view_all
`

Comment: And that matches the route you're using in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try "rake routes" on the console to see the structure of your routes?

Answer (score 0):

2 everybody: Make sure that you are calling right request, `GET` or `POST` as needed.