# Rails Controller uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102941/rails-controller-path-not-found) one:

My form:

```
</br>
<%= form_tag view_all_rater_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => 'Search by Set # or date' %></br>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "btn btn-link", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My routes:

```
  resource :rater, :only => [] do
    collection do
      get :rater_csv
      get :view_all
    end
  end
```

My controller:

```
class RaterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def view_all
    if params[:search]
      @ratings = RatingSet.find(:all, :conditions => ['id = ? or rating_date like ?', "#{params[:search]}", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
    else
      @ratings = RatingSet.all
    end
  end
end
```

My routes with a singular resource:

```
  rater_csv_rater GET    /rater/rater_csv(.:format)    raters#rater_csv
   view_all_rater GET    /rater/view_all(.:format)     raters#view_all
```

My routes with a plural resource:

```
  rater_csv_rater GET    /rater/rater_csv(.:format)    rater#rater_csv
   view_all_rater GET    /rater/view_all(.:format)     rater#view_all
```

Im really confused why defining a singular resource `raters#view_all`.

When I define a singular resource: `uninitialized constant RatersController`
When I define a plural resource: `undefined local variable or method`view_all_rater_path'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your routes to

```
resources :rater, :only => [] do
  collection do
    get :rater_csv
    get :view_all
  end
end
```

Comment: Still getting the same error `undefined local variable or method view_all_rater_path `

Comment: What does `rake routes` output?

Comment: `rater_csv_rater GET /rater/rater_csv(.:format)              raters#rater_csv`
`view_all_rater GET    /rater/view_all(.:format)                  raters#view_all`

Comment: I don't know what is the problem but you can use a plural resource as `resources :raters` and change the controllers class to `class RatersController < ApplicationController` and the filename to `raters_controller` and see if it works. Or you can just change your form tag to `<%= form_tag `/rater/view_all`, :method => 'get' do %>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your route add.

```
resources : raters
```

Comment: Still getting `undefined local variable or method `view_all_rater_path'`. (restarted my server also)

Comment: you actually need to specify to change `resource :raters` to `resources :raters`.

Comment: your route will change from `view_all_rater_path` to `view_all_raters_path`

Answer (score 0):

With a singular resource, you still need a pluralized controller, so it would be `RatersController` as the error says.

With a pluralized resource it would be `view_all_raters_path`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use namespace since you dont use any routes in rater

```
namespace :raters do
  get 'rater_csv'
  get 'view_all'
end
```

And rename your controller to `Raters` instead or `Rater`